# SELinux: My First Policies

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, security, selinux

I am at the point it's time to create my first policies.

I have read the [HowTo Security SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos#Security), watched the video [SELinux for mere mortals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WOKRaM-HI4) and multiple other documents I have received from the community.

I understand with a wide scope of what the purpose and intentions of SELinux is and now ready to start implementing policies with the the policy generation gui tool. Just not sure exactly where to start. There are so many options. I am looking to be coached through my first few policies and have my hand held.

I know must achieve a minimum the following:

- enable users to be able to ssh into the network | Got this figured out using the gui SELinux Management tool, very cool!
- **get the webpages to load on the network again**
- enable scp - got this figured out

SELinux is set to enforcing right now.  I am using CentOS7

[image]
[image]

Comment: so the question here is to _`get the webpages to load on the network again`_? can you describe more on this? what webpages you mean?

Comment: /var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/index.htlm is run on httpd and is not publishing to http(s) because default SELinux is set to enforcing.  I have to add a policy to allow httpd to communicate with http(s) just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Okay I got all the websites resolved on the network. Here is what I did;
I updated the /var/www/ files since I am currently using non standard directories. Had to give permission for SELinux to communicate with httpd.

I had to fix one of the pages because the images weren't loading. I

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/home/www(/.*)? restorecon -R /var/www
```

and that's pretty much it. So my use case is complete for the time being. This is a success for My Mission. Thanks for the input community. Hope this helps someone.